# JavaScript Prototype Object.create

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have two version code

```
    let Animal = function()
    {

    }

    Animal.prototype.voice = "Miau"


    let Cat = function()
    {

    }
    Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

    let flippy = new Cat();

    console.log(flippy.voice)
```

This version vorked and return "Miau" but second version

```
let Animal = function()
{
   this.voice = "Miau"
}


let Cat = function()
{

}
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);

let flippy = new Cat();

console.log(flippy.voice)
```

Worked  but return false Why I cant call flippy.voice? and how call flippy.voice?

Answer (score 4):

> Why I cant call `flippy.voice`?

Because there is no `voice` on `flippy`, because no code has ever been run that would have created it.

When deriving constructors in JavaScript, it's important to call the super's constructor from the sub's constructor:

```
let Cat = function() {
    Animal.call(this); // <====
};
```

If you do that, then the code in `Animal` is run, and the instance will have a `voice` property.

Note: It's also useful to fix up the `constructor` property on `Cat.prototype`:

```
let Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat; // <===
```

---

That said, having `Animal` set the `voice` to `"Miau"` seems...wrong. Perhaps accept it as an argument?

```
let Animal = function(voice) {
    this.voice = voice;
};

let Cat = function() {
    Animal.call(this, "Miau");
};

let Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;

let flippy = new Cat();
console.log(flippy.voice); // "Miau"
```

---

Of course, here in 2017, you can use `class` syntax (transpiling if necessary for older target environments) to simplify:

```
class Animal {
    constructor(voice) {
        this.voice = voice;
    }
}

class Cat extends Animal {
    constructor() {
        super("Miau");
    }
}

let flippy = new Cat();
console.log(flippy.voice); // "Miau"
```

Comment: I think extends with Object.create(function.prototype)  the same thing

Comment: @MuradSofiyev: The same thing as what? It's not the same thing as calling `Animal` from `Cat`, and it doesn't set `constructor` to the right value.